# partition, lead, left join. difference between different line data time-s

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have data about Engine working Hours. data consists of:

- `object ID` - Engine name
- `Stop from` - date time format. Line is created when engine stops.
- `Start to` - date time format.

I need to get information about how long engines are working per day. In order to do so i need to take for ex: first record of stop to (which means engine started working) end deduce the next line of stop from (where engine has stopped working)

In order to do so I came to a conclusion that i have to use partition lead and left join.

```
select 
object id, 
engine start (stop to) , 
engine stop (alias after joining), 
time_difference (datediff between engine start "stop to" and engine stop "stop from" alias)
```

after i partition and each line will have its own ID ill need to leftjoin with where Partitioned line ID "lead" (or just is "+1" or ">") to current partitioned line ID.

this is what i managed to work around the task but i'm new to sql and i can't finish the task. any suggestion how can i get it done?

[image]

Comment: What version of mysql are you on. Also can you add sample data and expected output as text to your question.

Comment: actually i'am on sql server. 

here is URL:   https://ibb.co/iWLHDx

and here is sample data  


OBJECTID STOPFROM STOPTO
OBJ_0004944 5/19/2017 6:00 5/26/2017 11:30
OBJ_0004944 5/27/2017 0:00 5/27/2017 17:00
OBJ_0004944 6/1/2017 23:59 8/30/2017 10:28
OBJ_0004944 9/2/2017 10:00 9/7/2017 0:00
OBJ_0005018 5/3/2017 12:00 5/3/2017 22:32
OBJ_0005018 5/4/2017 6:30 5/17/2017 19:15
OBJ_0005018 5/20/2017 21:33 5/21/2017 0:37
OBJ_0005018 5/21/2017 18:00 5/24/2017 4:00
OBJ_0005018 5/26/2017 21:00 5/27/2017 8:00
OBJ_0005018 6/5/2017 13:00 7/8/2017 16:08

Comment: You should change the tags to remove mysql and add sqlserver. Mysql and sqlserver are not the same and many useful features(for this question) in sqlserver are not available in mysql (such as partition).

Comment: thank you for advice. i have changed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query *appends* the corresponding `stopfrom` date to each row:

```
SELECT
    testdata.*,
    LEAD(stopfrom, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY stopto) AS next_stopfrom
FROM testdata
```

To calculate the time difference:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        testdata.*,
        LEAD(stopfrom, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY stopto) AS next_stopfrom
    FROM testdata
)
SELECT cte.*, DATEDIFF(minute, stopto, next_stopfrom)
FROM cte
```

Comment: after slight modification it worked perfectly. thank you.